# adobe edge | jquery path not referencing correctly.

Tags: javascript, jquery, adobe-edge

I got various ways to get attr() to work. However this one stomps me…. It’s just the last line. The path is not correct. Can someone glance at it for me see what I’m missing.

```
sym.setVariable(“box”, sym.createChildSymbol(‘box’,’Stage’)) ;
sym.getVariable(“box”).getSymbolElement().attr(‘id’,”newId”);
var boxId = sym.getVariable(“box”).getSymbolElement().attr(‘id’);
```

**//bottom not firing**

```
sym.getVariable(“box”).$(boxId).animate({opacity: 1, left:”+=400px”});
```

Comment: By `“box”` or `‘box’` do you mean `"box"`? The former will throw a syntax error, but `"box"` won't throw a syntax error.

Comment: @soktinpk dont think its specific to what you mentioned. no syntax errors. I think the addition on line two - changing the id attribute - for some reason throws off the "path structure in the .animate() line. Something to do with either line two or the last. I think.